# Rails Cucumber How to check if user is logged in before going to editing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have developed Rails application where user needs to be logged in to edit character he created earlier. Now I am trying to test my edit character function and I have created edit character scenario. Here is my files:

features/character.feature

```
     Feature: Character

       @javascript
       Scenario: Visiting characters listing page
         Given I am a new, authenticated user
         When I go to characters index page
         Then I should see characters listing page
```

characters_steps.rb

```
   Given /^I am a new, authenticated user$/ do
     email = 'ademimisel@gmail.com'
     password = 'pass1234'

     visit '#/login'
     fill_in 'email', :with => email
     fill_in 'password', :with => password
     click_button "Sign in"
   end

  When(/^I go to characters index page$/) do
    visit '#/'
    expect(page).to have_content("Characters")
  end

  Then(/^I should see characters listing page$/) do
    pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete     actions
  end
```

When I run, first step pass successfully but second not, because cucumber not register that sign up was successfully done and page are not redirected to edit page

Comment: @Thomas Walpole has the correct answer, you need to `expect` something on the page that only a `user` would see. Perhaps, once they log in they will now see "Sign Out" or something, or an alert that says they have logged in successfully. 

You should look at installing the 'launchy' gem that will allow you to run the `save_and_open_page` breakpoint anywhere in your capybara code to see what capybara sees and perhaps narrow down where the code is breaking.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have created a user in the database matching the username and password, all you need is a final line in your "I am a new, authenticated user" step that checks for something that is shown on the page after logging in.

```
Given /^I am a new, authenticated user$/ do
  email = 'ademimisel@gmail.com'
  password = 'pass1234'

  visit '#/login'
  fill_in 'email', :with => email
  fill_in 'password', :with => password
  click_button "Sign in"
  expect(page).to have_text("You are now logged in") # or whatever message is displayed to indicate successfull login - if using RSpec
  # page.assert_text("You are now logged in") # if not using RSpec
end
```

Comment: I tried this, but it not working too. It looks like that after `click_button` page is not redirected to page where is message "you are successfully logged in", and then in next step when I visit `#/` it fails because it not recognize that I registered in previous step.

Comment: @MišelAdemi Is that a valid username and password for an account you've created in the test system ?  You don't show creating the account in your steps, and if the account doesn't exist then the login will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If a user needs to be logged in before they can do something then you need to have the ability to 'register' as a user 'before' you can implement this scenario. Assuming you have done this you should be able to write something like

```
Given I am registered
And I am logged in
When I view characters
Then I should see a list of characters
```

You can implement the steps as follows

```
Given 'I am registered' do
  @i = create_registered_user
end

Given 'I am logged in' do
  login as: @i
end
```

and implement these using a step helper module

```
module RegistrationStepHelper
  def login(as:)
    ...

  def create_registered_user
    ...

end
World RegistrationStepHelper
```

You should extract the code you've previously written to do these tasks and use that in these methods.

Now if you haven't got this sort of capability from the code you have already written you need to create it and use it to ensure that there is a registered user in the database before you login to view your characters.

From your question and the code you've posted there is no indication that such a user is in the database. Each scenario starts with an empty database and your scenario is not registering a user.